# cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?

Tags: boot, password, encryption

Today I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop running Windows 8.1 using `Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.1.exe`. When I finished the installation, I was asked to reboot. I did so but the passphrase wasn't accepted. I had the same password for my user and the disks which I had encrypted with Ubuntu's own tool. I am sure my password is correct as I tried it many times. On every 3rd try I am redirected to a page with lots of command lines. At end of that page I see:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:

-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

      -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait for long enough?)
     -Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
-Missing modules /cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu) built-in shell (ash)
Enter "help" for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I am totally new to Linux and I need help with this. I have already tried various things on this site but they didn't help me. I have no risk of losing files as I have them on my other computer which I am currently using.

I could totally re-install Ubuntu but i don't know how to do it. Can anyone help with it?

Comment: Windows 8.1 might be UEFI and secure boot. Try disabling secure-boot in BIOS, and install ubuntu with a live CD or USB stick (just open the iso with 7zip under Windows and copy the contents to any bootable FAT fomated usb stick). I hope this gives you a first Idea. I have no time to write a full How-To. Here is some documentation regarding secure-boot: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thank you for advise, i managed to solve the problem that way

Comment: very good. If you solved this problem, nothing can stop you becoming an ubuntu guru :) Have fun!